# How to find an element based on a CSS style value and simulate a click on it

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to load a site and click on a link that i specifically parse out. So far I have this (not sure if it actually works at all to grab the element)

```
public HtmlElement FindLink() {

        HtmlElement theLinkToClick = null;

        foreach (HtmlElement link in wbcSample.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))                     {
            // Trying to see if it returns something... it didn't...
            MessageBox.Show(link.Style.ToString());
            /*  if (link.Style) {
                return link;
            } */
        }
        return theLinkToClick;
   }
```

So i am trying to get an element on a page (using the provided webBrowser tool in C#) and select between 4 of them based on the background image. The style is provided in the HTML that i parse out, so that is not an issue.

Here is an example of the html that i am dealing with where i want to select the HTML element background-image and see if it contains a certain value. If it does, i want to click on that element.

```
<input type="submit" name="verify" value="" style="cursor: pointer; border: 0px; 

height: 100px; width: 100px; background-image: url(imgs/4.jpg); color: transparent; margin: 
0px; opacity: 0.4; filter: alpha(opacity=40);" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40">
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can map a CSS selector to XPath: http://plasmasturm.org/log/444/

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, or how to read the link, would you mind elaborating, the term is alien to me?

Comment: When you're reading HTML through either an XML parser or HtmlAgilityPack, you can find nodes through XPath.  If you know the CSS selector which contains the background image you want, you can convert that CSS selector into an XPath and retrieve the node(s).

Comment: I'm doing this in C#, so C# reads it through an XML parser? You'll have to excuse my lack of knowlege in this area.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comments, bad advice.